# FID opens unnecessarily on latest OSx of 10.14/10.15 causing data corruption with Word files on network drives(Windows/Linux File servers)

Tags: macos, high-sierra, mojave, ms-office, smb

The latest MAC 10.14.x and MAC 10.15.x OS have degraded their behavior with Word applications on Network drives mapped via SMB. These network drive are shared drives on Windows-2019 File server or it can be on any Linux File server.

Issues:

A) 10.14.x and above versions of MAC always open a FID for Word application(on n/w drive) even though user hasn't opened it and these FIDs are kept opened forever. Thorough testing has revealed that this issue is not seen on MAC10.12/10.13 .

The problem with this issue is whenever user deletes a word file on n/w drive,since a FID was unnecessarily opened by the client already,the delete happens post a rename of the file to be deleted. For eg: when we try to delete File1.docx , the client will rename it to .smbdelete and delete the File1.docx.

This is fine if the user intention is a real delete but if it was unintended delete and if Salvage/Recover of deleted files are enabled for n/w drive ,then there is *no way* that file can be recycled back to n/w drive since the file is in .smbdelete format which can't be read and converted to File1.docx and most of the times, the .smbdelete files are not persistent unless they are flushed by client.

This is one of the use-cases of this unnecessary FID open by MAC10.14/10.15 clients and when there are multiple users working on this n/w drive on same file, there will be many more file lock issues in the enterprise due to this FID opened.

Anyone heard/observed this issue?

Are there any posts/fixes about this behavior that Apple introduced from MAC10.14 ? This is really degrading MAC usability and corrupting n/w users data is making lives of Shared drive administrators difficult!!!!